# File `data.csv' already exists on the system

Tags: filecontents

Why does this Warning appear when using filecontents? :
**File `data.csv' already exists on the system.**
Does anyone know how i can remove this warning?

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
a,b,c,d
1,4,5,1
2,3,1,5
3,5,6,1
4,1,4,9
5,3,4,7
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [x=a, y=c, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: you can force filecontents to overwrite the file with `\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{data.csv}` if you are sure that you want that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have tried that before but the warning is still not gone :/

Comment: if you get really a message for data2.csv (and not data.csv) you will have to find the place where this file is written.

Comment: i misspelled that one. it was meant to say  data.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's by design. You'd need to rewrite the definition of `\filec@ntents` to omit the warning. Using a patch is not really feasible, because this definition is given in a very particular category code context.

Using `silence` (besides being a bit risky) isn't possible either, because it only silences warnings, but this message is in the “info” category (but differently from other informational messages, it also appears on the console and not only in the log file).

I find much more annoying the `pgfplots` warning

```
Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true': document ha
s been generated with the most recent feature set (\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}).
```

that's useless and unformatted.